# IE8 table td border

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table

Recently I have create table and I don't know why but in Internet Explorer the cells have got borders, don't know why, and it is mashing the whole table.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Dragon</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
</head>
<style>
td{
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#e2e3e7" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;border:none;">
<table id="Table_01" width="602" style="table-layout:fixed;box-sizing: border-box;" align="center" height="3401" border="0px #ffffff solid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="10">
            <img style="display:block"   src="images/Concept1_01.gif" width="1" height="394" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="47">
            <img style="display:block"   src="images/Concept1_02.gif" width="600" height="56" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img style="display:block"   src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="56" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img style="display:block"   src="images/Concept1_03.gif" width="26" height="59" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="27">
            <img style="display:block"   src="images/Concept1_04.gif" width="307" height="14" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="19" rowspan="3">
            <img style="display:block"   src="images/Concept1_05.gif" width="267" height="59" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img style="display:block"   src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="14" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you would like to change doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and try setting `border="0"` on table?

Answer (score 1):

There are no borders when I test on IE 9 with a verbatim copy of the code posted. The table is malformed in many ways and does not comply with the HTML table model, so the rendering may vary a lot, but if you see borders, or something that looks like a border, it probably comes from some code that was not included.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at your `table` indicates that the heights in your `tr`s account for about `600`, while the `table` height, specified in the `table`, is about `3000`. Therefore the borders could be padding of some sort.